# Best practice for reading all files in a directory and dealing with file strings

Tags: php, string, file, directory

In Java there is the File object that I can use to refer to a file's parent, list children files, and other useful functions (methods).  These methods can return File objects, so I don't need to deal with a file's string.  Instead, I can just manage the object.  This makes things nice and neat and less prone to my typos.

In PHP I am concatenating the directory string with the file name string to get the file string.  It works fine, but this seems gimmicky to me, and I would like to know if there is a better way.  Is there a PHP equivalent to the built in Java File object?

Here is my code for reading all files in a directory and printing out their contents line by line:

```
$reportDir = realpath(RESOURCE_PATH . "/userFiles/uploadedReports");
if ($dirHandle = opendir($reportDir)) {
    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($dirHandle))) {
        if ($entry != "." && $entry != ".."){
            $fileString = $reportDir . "/" . $entry;
            $fileHandle = fopen($fileString, "r");
            while (!feof($fileHandle) ) {
               $line = fgets($fileHandle);
               echo $line . "<br />";
            }
            fclose($fileHandle);
            $i++;
        }
    }
    closedir($dirHandle);
}
```

In case you want to know exactly what I am trying to accomplish with this code, I am going to display to the user an HTML table with data from a tab delimited file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there is its an SPL class called [`SplFileObject`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.splfileobject.php) which has methods for dealing with the file contents... There is also its parent [`SplFileInfo`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.splfileinfo.php) which has methods for basic file information (mtime, path, filename, etc..). There are also a [series of iterators](http://www.php.net/manual/en/spl.iterators.php) for dealing with iterating over structures such as a directory/file tree.

Comment: SPL is definitely 'best practice' in my opinion.

Comment: Thank you! I'm looking into the [Directory Iterator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php) right now.